# How to render XML output in MVC view

Tags: javascript, xml, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
<header>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="float-left">
            <p class="site-title">
                <a href="~/">ASP.NET Web API</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<div id="body">
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <hgroup class="title">
                <h1>
                    Calculator</h1>
            </hgroup>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
    <input id="id" type="text" />
    <p />
    <input id="Plus" type="button" value="+" /><input id="Minus" type="button" value="-" />
    <p />
    <input id="id2" type="text" />
    <p />
    ________________________________

    <p />
    <label id="answer"></label>
    </section>
</div>
```

this is my cshtml document and I need to have the label answer show a value from when I click plus which will then go to my api an get `/api/add?id=value&id2=value` then it just gets and XML document and I can't do anything with this XML document. How do I display the value from the XML document for answer and IT CAN NOT USE JSON, it has to be XML output and using javascript is ok.

Comment: did you tried to parse your xml into json and use json data in your mvc view(cshtml document)? alternative way would be parsing your xml content to viewmodel and passing view-model to mvc view.

Comment: I can not use json ever!

Comment: Did you tried to parse your xml content to a viewmodel and pass view-model to your MVC view.

Comment: do it through $.ajax({} , look at provided example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use jquery  you can do

```
<script>

 $('#buttonID').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({

  url : "url/to/api?params=1",
  dataType : "xml",
  success : function(data){

   var dataAsXml = $.parseXml(data);

   var answer = $(dataAsXml).find("answerNode");

    $('#answerLabelID').text(answer);

  });   // end Ajax call added paren and semi
}); // end button click




</script>
```

Comment: Here is a link to show you how to get to the node you want in the xml returned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716517/jquery-xpath-find

Comment: Can you verify that your API is returning xml?

Comment: Can you verify that your API is returning xml? also keep in mind that the IDs I put in for the answer id label and your button is need to be the IDs you are using. In addition the $.ajax function depends on jQuery being loaded. http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/ . I recommend you learn/use firebug for Firefox specifically the javascript console and network panel for debugging Ajax calls.